# After using POI with excel the .xlsx file gets corrupted therefore the code complains about InvalidFormat

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I've been working with excel document to read/write data to it using POI API with Java. I get an invalid format exception. The file size becomes 0(zero). The format of the file is the same when I look at it manually so I am not sure why after using exactly the same code at certain point of execution the file gets corrupted. I always make a backup of the document manually, if changes are in, otherwise if file is corrupted I have no way of repairing or restoring it.

Here is an exception:

```
org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Package should contain a content type part [M1.13]
    at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:41)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:218)
Caused by: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Package should contain a content type part [M1.13]
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.getPartsImpl(ZipPackage.java:199)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.getParts(OPCPackage.java:665)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:274)
    at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:39)
    ... 4 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Are you sure you have an excel format that the API supports? Because Excel supports A LOT of formats, including HTML files. You should open it in a text editor or (preferably) a hex editor to see what you actually have.

Comment: I faced this same issue before. Chances are, some external force is corrupting your file, or you have a bug in your output stream/flushing code. In my case the document was on a shared network drive, and someone else had it opened during runtime. Make sure to always have the spreadsheet closed while your running your code and that nobody touches it while your executing. Also might be a good idea to code in some backup feature that creates a copy / pastes it somewhere so you dont have to do that manually. Hope that helps!

Comment: Also forgot to mention, if your code crashes while writing to the stream, it will for sure corrupt it. Try with a test document and kill your code at some point in the writing process, it should produce exactly what your seeing.